# How to pass a Javascript var into a href tag?

Tags: javascript, html, href, var

I have used a function to capture the Query String value of "name" - i.e. imagine a party invite site;

https://cometomyparty.com?name=phil

The function used is;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getQuerystring(){
    var q=document.location.toString();
    q=q.split("?");
    q=q[1].split("&");
    var str=""
    for(i=0;i<q.length;i++){
      tmp=q[i].split("=")
      str+=" "+tmp[1]+"<br />"
    }
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=str
  }
  onload=function(){
    getQuerystring()
  }
</script>
```

Then I can call the value of 'name' using id="name" where I want to use this on my page, i.e. in the heading, I could say, Phil, looking forward to having you at the party...

How can I dynamically append my 'name' value (var str) within a html link placement i.e.

```
<a href="http://example.com?name=str">Link Text</a>
```

Which would return, in the example above;

```
http://example.com?name=phil
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag directly or by using `.setAttribute`:

```
// Using .href:
document.getElementById("name").href=str;

// Using . setAttribute:
document.getElementById("name").setAttribute ("href", str);
```

---

*Be aware that you should have that `<br/>` tag in the `src` of the link.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick='goToPage(event)'>Link Text</a>

<script>

function goToPage(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location='http://example.com?name='+str;
}

</script>
```

Ideally you would want to use jquery where you could use:

```
$('#link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('src');
    window.location=link+str
});
```

You would of course want to remove "str" from the  href

Comment: Note: `str` isn't currently being defined in either snippet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice

Comment: An empty href attribute fails W3C validation too. If you're gonna go with this method, at least put *something* in there, even just a `#`

Comment: Thanks @Scoots, I missed that. I have updated my answer to show that